# Combining traditional and spatial indices in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, gis

I have timestamped location data.

I want Postgres to efficiently execute queries that are bounded in time and space.  e.g.

```
select * 
from tracking_tags
where ts >= '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
and ts < '2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
and lat > 40.0
and lat < 50.0
and long < 0.0
and long > -10.0
```

How should I approach this from an indexing point of view?

I am confused because I think I might need to choose between a normal b-tree index on `ts` and a GIST index on `lat`/`long` `POINTs`, but I need a composite index (or possibly two).

Assume a decade of data, with a thousand records per day.

(P.S. Apologies for nonsense SQL, I haven't yet switched from MySQL to Postgres - but this *is* a Postgres question.)

Comment: This is not a postgis query. You are just doing comparisons of decimals and there aren't any geometry or geography fields here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes for this particular table schema could vary greatly depending on what what information you need to fetch.

For example, the query below would likely use the index effectively

```
CREATE INDEX ON tracking_tags USING gist (point(lat,long), ts);

SELECT * 
FROM tracking_tags
WHERE point(lat,long) <@ box(point(40,-10),point(50,0)) AND
      ts <@ tstzrange'[1990-01-01,2000-01-01)' AND
      lat NOT IN (40, 50) AND long NOT IN (-10, 0);
```

Comment: What do the "lat/long NOT IN..." do and why are they needed in addition to the "<@ box"?

Comment: @chrisdew the operator `point <@ box` is optimised in gist indexes, but it's inclusive. Your sample query requires exclusive, so this uses a fast indexed inclusive approach first, and then filters out any points that are actually touching the box's frame.

Answer (score 2):

The [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) extension allows you to make a gist index on timestamps which makes it possible to combine them with PostGIS indexes. PostgreSQL also can [use multiple indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) in one query. You'll have to test and see which combination performs the best.